# Recommend on how to set the php object more lazily?

Tags: php, oop

Here is the way I do:

```
$aNewObject = new MyObj();
$aNewObject->set_id($row->id);
$aNewObject->set_user_id($row->user_id);
$aNewObject->set_title($row->title);
$aNewObject->set_url($row->url);
$aNewObject->set_description($row->description);                       
$aNewObject->set_status($row->status);
```

as you can see, I follow a name convention, which the object and the data base field is 100% match, I think there should have a way to help me to do it lazier, any recommendation?

Comment: What do you mean by lazier? To not type that much?

Answer (score 3):

You can get even lazier by only writing

```
$aNewObject = new MyObj($row);
```

and having a constructor that sets the object's properties based on the contents of `$row`

Comment: additional tweaking of this can be: the constructor can either accept $row as array to directly use the contents of array, or accept an ID to fetch data from database and load the contents from database.

Comment: Just saying: You should make constructors simple, not complex. They should only initialize the new object and should not contain much code. Don't overuse constructors.

Comment: @hakre Looking at the code he's writing, it's just a copy constructor, that's a pretty standard constructor to write.

Comment: @Dan: Yes, was more referring to the comment suggesting to put  database access in the constructor. For copying I would suggest a helper function in the object to keep the constructor more readable.

Answer (score 1):

You could do the setting dynamically by iterating over the fields (if that is meant by lazier):

```
$fields = array('user_id', ...);
foreach($fields as $field)
{
    $setter = "set_{$field}";
    $aNewObject->$setter($row->{$field});
}
```

It depends then where you want to place that code. Either just inline, as part of a function of `MyObj` (`importRow($row)`) or in a global helper function that always calls all setters matching object properties.

Within the class constructor:

```
$aNewObject = new MyObj($row);

class MyObj
{
    public function __construct($row = null)
    {
        ...
        $this->importRow($row);
    }

    public function importRow($row = null)
    {
        if (null === $row)
            return;

        foreach($row as $field => $value)
        {
            $setter = "set_{$field}";
            $this->$setter($value);
        }
    }
   ...    
}
```

To prevent duplicate code across different classes (missing traits support in PHP < 5.4), a global static function or object can do it:

```
$aNewObject = new MyObj();
new Setter($aNewObject, $row);

# or

$aNewObject = Setter::fill('MyObj', $row);


class Setter
{
    private $object;
    public function __construct($class, $data)
    {
        // works on classnames or objects
        if (is_string($class))
            $object = new $class();
        else
            $object = $class;

        $this->object = $this->import($object, $data);
    }

    private function import($object, $data)
    {
        foreach($data as $field => $value)
        {
            $setter = "set_{$field}";
            $object->$setter($value);
        }
        return $object;
    }

    public function getObject()
    {
        return $this->object;
    }

    public static function fill($class, $data)
    {
        $self = new __CLASS__($class, $data);
        return $self->getObject();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lazier, it is not recommended, because it will make it hard to maintain by other programmers.

If you still want to do that, you should do with PHP reflection: http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.reflection.php

or as @hakre answered.

Comment: y it is hard to maintain? You mean, it is more easy to maintain by setting it manually?

Comment: Thind happened by "Magic" will make it harder to understand by other programmers. it is not so bad, but you should think twice when designing it.

Comment: That's a valid point. If you have magic clue inside your code that solves things dynamically, it can be more hard to track in debugging. If you have got a lot of debugging, you won't be more lazy later on :)

Comment: but ppl always say to DRY the code, if I doing this manually, it seems have some violate with this idea.